# Flash and Software based vulnerabilities

Tags: vulnerability

Assuming an attacker does not have access to your LAN\Router etc... How could they take control of your web cam\system peripherals\other resources via a flash vulnerability. That's what I hear on the news, and I would like to be made familiar of the methods used.

I can possibly see it happening if the webserver\web master wants to attack you, as he would have your ip address and other identifying information and I guess go from there. But how would an attacker that doesn't have access to the webserver launch a lateral attack on the user's of that site? And how are flash's vulnerabilities leveraged?

BONUS:Finally, bonus question, for pentesting I hear that we have to use a sniffer like nmap to scan for vulnerabilities on particular ports\services on a host on a network. I guess those vulns are previously discovered and written down on some database on the web. But my question is: once we have a target computer, how do tools like metasploit work? does the attacking computer create a particular packet that we know the target computer will handle in a self-defeating manner?

I am new to all this, so excuse my ignorance.

Comment: links in emails to malicious sites, ad networks, etc. There are lots of ways to get someone to your malicious Flash

Comment: How does that work with big sites like yahoo? How does a hacker attack users of yahoo? What you are saying is you have to run malicious flash content on your devices\links i understand that as i said a webmaster could attack the users. but how would users attack other users in the example of yahoo? I guess the attacker would have to compromise yahoos webserver, but beyond that not sure

Comment: As I say: ad networks.

Comment: by the way: your bonus question is actually a separate question - can you pull it into its own question? But before you do, you want to look at "exploits" - these are how you take advantage of vulnerabilities and each exploit works in their own unique way, some are network-based, some are local

Answer (score 1):

It is (in my opinion) possible to spread Flash Mal easily through every possible source:

- Obscure Social Media/Sharing Sites
- Email Scams
- Advertising Networks
- Hacked websites riddled with hidden flash content

For example 18 Hours Ago (from this post) Adobe fixed a vulnerability (CVE-2015-7645)

There was a reason Steve Jobs never wanted Flash on iOS